robots.txt is served with html structure instead of plain text
I like to serve a robots.txt file and tried it by adding it to the middleware. But instead of a txt file, on localhost it creates a html structure with text as below. And in production it creates the html structure with no text at all. Seems like the content type is overwritten or not respected.
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">User-agent: * Allow: / Sitemap: https://gnossi-wohnig.ch/sitemap
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>

The middleware:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import acceptLanguage from "accept-language";
import { fallbackLng, languages, cookieName } from "./app/i18n/settings";

acceptLanguage.languages(languages);

export const config = {
  // matcher: '/:lng*'
  matcher: [
    "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|assets|favicon.ico|sw.js|site.webmanifest).*)",
  ],
};

export function middleware(req) {
  let lng;
  if (req.cookies.has(cookieName))
    lng = acceptLanguage.get(req.cookies.get(cookieName).value);
  if (!lng) lng = acceptLanguage.get(req.headers.get("Accept-Language"));
  if (!lng) lng = fallbackLng;

  // robots.txt
  if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/robots.txt")) {
    let content =
      "User-agent: *\nAllow: /\nSitemap: https://gnossi-wohnig.ch/sitemap";

    return new NextResponse(content, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" },
    });
  }

  if (
    !languages.some((loc) => req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${loc}`)) &&
    !req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/_next")
  ) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(`/${lng}${req.nextUrl.pathname}`, req.url)
    );
  }

  if (req.headers.has("referer")) {
    const refererUrl = new URL(req.headers.get("referer"));
    const lngInReferer = languages.find((l) =>
      refererUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${l}`)
    );
    const response = NextResponse.next();
    if (lngInReferer) response.cookies.set(cookieName, lngInReferer);
    return response;
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}


